# Replace null value in column name when importing flat file with powershell

Tags: sql, powershell

I am importing a flat file to a SQL table in powershell, here's my code:

```
$full = $location + $file + $extension
    $all = Get-Content $full
    $columns = $all[0]
    $columns = $columns.Replace(";","] VARCHAR(255), [")
    $table = "CREATE TABLE " + $file + "([" + $columns + "] VARCHAR(255))"
```

I have the `;` set as the delimiter however the first line in the text file starts with a semicolon:

```
;Column2;Column3;Column4;Column5;Column6

Value1;Value2;Value3;Value4;Value5;Value6
```

therefore SQL cannot import due to this null column. I do need this column however so cannot skip. I would like to replace the null value with a `0`, I tried:

```
$columns = $columns.Replace("","0")
```

however this did not work, is there a short hand way to this?

Comment: Can you not just concatenate "0" and $columns before doing the replace?

Comment: @DanL can you elaborate?

Comment: I mean after the line $columns = $all[0], you could do $columns = "0" + $columns so you then have the string "0;Column2;Column3;Column4;Column5;Column6"

Comment: @DanL yup that did it, I feel dumb.. how do I mark that as answer? lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just concatenate "0" and $columns before doing the replace?

More explicitly, after the line

```
$columns = $all[0]
```

you could do

```
$columns = "0" + $columns
```

so you then have the string "0;Column2;Column3;Column4;Column5;Column6"